# Loop add new record to array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a opt variable in Typescript

```
let opt = [{}];
```

if I want to add multiple children to opt variable to below exsample with for loop

```
options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
]
```

how can I coding

```
for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I want to use for select option value in html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff2aja?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Array in Array element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640538/how-to-add-array-in-array-element)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add each item in `options` to `opt`, then:

```
let opt = [];

let options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
]

options.forEach(x => opt.push(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to push the value into `opt[]`

> Example:

```
for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    opt.push( { i } );
}
```

Please make changes as per your requirement for what you want to push into the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

compomnet.html

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.name}}</option>
</select>
```

component.ts

```
options = [
    { name: "option1", value: 1 },
    { name: "option2", value: 2 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use in select option, you don't need to loop anything in .ts, you can use `*ngFor` directive in template to display the options.

Try like this:

.html

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option [value]="null">Select</option>
  <option *ngFor="let opt of options" [value]="opt.value">{{opt.name}}</option>
</select>

<p>selected : {{selected}} </p>
```

.ts

```
options = [{ name: "option1", value: 1 }, { name: "option2", value: 2 }];
selected = null;
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ff2aja?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Don't need to loop anything? I can see the loop in html.

Comment: @AliWahab I mean no loop in .ts file, the standard syntax of Angular template using directive `*ngFor` will do.

Comment: Yeah just wanted to correct you if somebody visit this page in future. Well I think the question is not straight. He need to loop through options through .ts, like legacy jQuery style.